# Calculate the winding number

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]

I am trying to calculate the winding number of the curve $\gamma$ at point $a$. My strategy is $\oint_\gamma \frac{1}{z-a} \,dz = \oint _{\gamma_2} \frac{1}{z-a}\,dz = 2\pi i$ as the corridor gets closer. But this is wrong since the winding number should clearly be $2$ rather than $1$. Why is this argument wrong?

Comment: it is not true that $\int_\gamma \frac{dz}{z-a} = \int_{\gamma_2} \frac{dz}{z-a}$ (why do you think it is ?) and it is correct that $ \int_{\gamma} \frac{dz}{z-a} = 4 i \pi$

Comment: By CIT for star-shaped regions.

Comment: your red contour $C$ is closed, and $\frac{1}{z-a}$ isn't holomorphic inside, that's why $\int_C \frac{dz}{z-a} = - 2i\pi$

Comment: I am applying the CIT to the red contour plus the black contour. Together they are a closed contour, then $\oint_\gamma \frac{1}{z-a}  - \oint _{\gamma_2} \frac{1}{z-a} = 0$, isn't this right?

Comment: No. Try with $\gamma = (e^{i t},t \in [0,4\pi])$

Comment: Can you explain why it is wrong? I am really confused.

Comment: Oh! I konw the problem!

Comment: ok explain it :)

Comment: To get a star-convex region, I need the red region to be extended further to the upper part of the curve.

Comment: not really, anyway your notation are unclear, so whatever. ${}{}$